# how to list the directory, its size and the user that owns it

Tags: linux, unix

Say there is shared unit that has allocated space to run some analytics, there is not really a limit per user however it has to be often monitored so the user don't leave  "trash" that might consume space.
What I want to do is to list all the folders within that  directory, but also include the owner and the size of the directory.

Right now I use

```
df /server/shared/alloc
```

and the output is:

```
Filesystem    512-blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/work    1027604480 302184640   71%     6877     1% /server/shared/alloc
```

But this will only give me the % used instead of what I asked before.

Sorry if this is a noobie question, i'm not really a sys admin just want to be able to monitor so I can email the users that take a lot of space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a single command that provides all the information you want. You can either write a script or use a combination of

```
  du /server/shared/alloc
  find /server/shared/alloc -type d -ls
```

The first will give you the total disk usage for (all the files in) each folder and subfolder

The second will give you the ownership of the folders and folders (but not the ownership of the files in those folders)

Note that a directory has a size (related to the number of files in it) that is different from the size of it's contents.

I use the following words interchangeably: folder; subfolder; directory; subdirectory.

Answer (score 3):

If you set up quotas (any value is fine, even setting the whole volume as a limit) then you can use `quota` to display usage information by the users.

Comment: sorry, like I said I'm a bit of a new.. can you explain ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota

Comment: yeah I know what the quota is but how to use it?

Comment: quota /serv/test/test/ doesnt work

Comment: Of course not. You didn't set up quotas.